Looking at the developer's source code doesn't reveal all the code
Newbie here, but I didn't know where else to go.  I have a very rudimentary understanding of html/css.
I am trying to use python to extract data from the major league soccer website to populate a database I am building.  This site here lists the lineups from an old match:  https://www.atlutd.com/competitions/mls-regular-season/2017/matches/atlvsrbny-03-05-2017/lineups.  I use the chrome browser.
When I click ctl+u, I believe I am getting the html source code.  This same code is what I download when I use python tools like requests.  However, it doesn't include the player or manager names.
When I use the chrome developer tools, appearing at the side of the webpage, a whole different set of elements appear that have the information I need.  None of these div elements show up when I hit ctl+u.
I feel like this is something simple I am missing, but my google searches have so far have turned up nothing.  Any nudge in the right direction is most appreciated.  Thank you for your time.


It looks to be loading the data from external APIs hosted at stats-api.mlssoccer.com and sportapi.atlutd.com.  This data gets loaded via JavaScript being executed in your browser, so you don't see this data when you view the source.
If you click "Network" and select "Fetch/XHR" and filter by "api" in your developer tools, then reload the page, you should see these API calls.
As it is an API, you may be able to use the API itself to get the data you need and not need to go down the messy scraping route.

Thank you so much.  I would send a gift basket if I could.
